# How to add request and response error anticeptors in redux toolkit query baseQuery

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How to added same anticeptors like this like in `Redux-toolkit-query`
Add a request interceptor

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
            // Do something before request is sent
            return config;
          }, function (error) {
            // Do something with request error
            return Promise.reject(error);
          });
```

This is current implementation for redux-toolkit-query .Now i want to add request and response anticeptors.i want once a user hits api if there is error in request it should reject or if error is in response.in both cases it should reject.

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api", // optional
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      // const state = getState();
      const token = UTILS.getCurrentUser();
      if (token) {
        headers.set("authorization", token.token);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});
```

Comment: What is `fetchBaseQuery`? This is a function that returns the object making the requests, and this is where you'd add the axios interceptors... assuming you are already using axios for your base queries. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to work with here?

Answer (score 0):

i think this might help you out:

first create axios service like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getCookie, setCookie, deleteCookie } from 'utils/global';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    headers: {}
    // headers: { 'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar' }
});

let isRefreshing = false;
let failedQueue = [];

const onErrorResponse = (error) => {
        
    return Promise.reject(error);
};

// Add a request interceptor
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        // Do something before request is sent
        const newConfig = config;
        const token = getCookie('Token');
        if (token) newConfig.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        newConfig.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'fa';
        return newConfig;
    },
    (error) => {
        // Do something with request error
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

// Add a response interceptor
instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
}, onErrorResponse);

export default instance;
```

then create Axios baseQuery for RTK Query using Axios service you created earlier.

```
import axios from 'services/request';

const axiosBaseQuery =
    () =>
    async ({ body, ...restArgs }) => {
        try {
            const result = await axios({ data: body, ...restArgs });
            return { data: result.data };
        } catch (axiosError) {
            const err = axiosError;
            return {
                error: {
                    status: err.response?.status,
                    data: err.response?.data || err.message
                }
            };
        }
    };

export default axiosBaseQuery;
```

then in `createApi` you can do this :

```
export const ApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery(),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      // stuff you like to do
    })
```